# How to access a logger object from other modules in a web application

Tags: python, global-variables, scope, web.py

I have my main.py as follows:

```
import logging
import os
import web

def is_test():
  if 'WEBPY_ENV' in os.environ:
    return os.environ['WEBPY_ENV'] == 'test'

app = web.application(router.urls, globals())

logging.basicConfig(filename="log/debug.log", level=logging.INFO)
global logger
logger = logging.getLogger("debug")

if (not is_test()) and __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Now, here I have defined a variable named `logger` as global. So, can I access this variable anywhere in my application w/o redefining it? I am using web.py.
Basically what i need is something like this. I want to initialize the logger once and I should be able to use it anywhere in my whole application. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to access any global variable since the `logging` module already provides access to logger objects anywhere in your code, that is, if you use:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("debug")
```

in other modules, you'll get the same logger object as in the main module.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand why you're using a "debug" logger when you can adjust the level of your logger to get the debug messages, but maybe yours was just an example or you really need that, so let's get to the point:

From the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html): *The key benefit of having the logging API provided by a standard library module is that* ***all Python modules can participate in logging,*** *so your application log can include your own messages integrated with messages from third-party modules.*

This means that you just need to configure your logging at the beginning of your application and after that when you need a logger you call `logging.getLogger(name)` and you get that logger.

So there's no need of "tracking" your `logger` variable with:

```
global logger
logger = logging.getLogger("debug")
```

because whenever you need to log from your `"debug"` logger (in the middle of whatever you want) you just do something like:

```
my_debug_logger = logging.getLogger("debug")
my_debug_logger.info('some message')
```

At the end the point is that when you import the logging module `import logging` you have access to each and every logger previously defined (and of course you can define new ones).